# Sending a Post Request using ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, request

I've been struggling to send a POST with a json to a webservice using ZF2. That's what I've been trying so far:

```
$array = array('nome' => 'cert123', 'certificado' => $cert);
$json = json_encode($array);

$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
]);
$request->setUri($this->uri);
$request->setMethod('POST'); 

$client = new Client();
$client->setAdapter('Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket');
$client->setEncType(Client::ENC_FORMDATA);
$client->setRawBody($json);

$response = $client->dispatch($request);
if ($response->isSuccess()) {
    echo "the post worked!";
} else {
    echo "the post failed";
}
```

It's always failing, but I don't get any errors, and the POST request in the network tab just keeps running. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Tnx

Comment: The network tab won't help you as the request is happening server side. Try echoing `$response->getBody()`?

Comment: Or try using a proxy like charles to monitor your requests.
This way you can find out exactly what you send, and what you receive.